# while loops for processing FITS files(python)

Tags: python, while-loop, fits

I am new at programming in python and am in the process of trying to create a setup of processing thousands of files with one piece of code in python. I created a practice folder to do this in. In it are two FITS files (FITS1.fits and FITS2.fits). I did the following to put them both in a .txt file:

```
ls > practice.txt
```

Here is what I did next:

```
$ python
import numpy
import pyfits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pylab
from pylab import *
import asciidata

a = asciidata.open('practice.txt')

print a[0][0] #To test to see if practice.txt really contains my FITS files FITS1.fits
i = 0
while i <=1 #Now I attempt a while loop to read data from columns in FITS files, plot the numbers desired, save and show the figures. I chose i <=1 because there are only two FITS files in the text(also because of zero-indexing). 

    b = pyfits.getdata(a[0][i]) # "i" will be the index used to use a different file when the while loop gets to the end

    time = b['TIME'] #'TIME' is a column in the FITS file
    brightness = b['SAP_FLUX']
    plt.plot(time, brightness)
    xlabel('Time(days)')
    ylabel('Brightness (e-/s)')
    title(a[0][i])

    pylab.savefig('a[0][i].png') #Here am I lost on how to get the while loop to name the saved figure something different every time. It takes the 'a[0][i].png' as a string and not as the index I am trying to make it be.

    pylab.show()

    i=i+1 # I placed this here, hoping that when the while loop gets to this point, it would start over again with a different "i" value
```

After pressing enter twice, I see the first figure as expected. Then I will close it and see the second. However, only the first figure is saved. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can change my loop to do what I need it to?

Comment: If you want help, please put in the effort to make your code here readable.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. For future reference, how would I make my code readable? I'm also new to this website.

Comment: @Iguananaut For future reference, Code Review is **not** a place for questions like this. Code Review requires code to be *working as intended* already.

Comment: If that's the case I withdraw my comment.  I was under the impression it was for more general comments on code--working or not--than specific problem statements.

Comment: @Iguananaut Sounds like you might want/need to read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Thanks--that's a helpful guide (IMO questions like this one shouldn't belong on SO either--but then it's hard for new users to know where *to* ask questions like this, so...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the i is being treated as the letter i, not the variable. If you wanted to keep this naming you could do something like:

```
FileName = 'a[0][%s].png' % i
pylab.savefig(FileName)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ChipJust, this does work. It results in my .png files named a[0][0], a[0][1] and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You should use glob to automatically get a the fits files as a list, from there using a for loop will let you iterate of the names of the files directly instead of using an index. When you call `plt.savefig`, you need to construct the file name you want to save it as. Here is the code cleaned up and put together:

```
from glob import glob
import pyfits
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

files = glob('*.fits')

for file_name in files:
    data = pyfits.getdata(file_name)
    name = file_name[:-len('.fits')] # Remove .fits from the file name

    time       = data['TIME']
    brightness = data['SAP_FLUX']

    plt.plot(time, brightness)

    plt.xlabel('Time(days)')
    plt.ylabel('Brightness (e-/s)')
    plt.title(name)

    plt.savefig(name + '.png')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Whoa! This is amazing. Glob is my new best friend. Thank you so much Trevor!

Comment: I have one more question, it seems that not all of my FITS files have the same construction in the data tables. For example, some files would need the code 
time = data['barytime']
or
brightness = data['ap_raw_flux']

Is there a way that you know of where I can make the for loop do this "or" that?

Comment: You can always check with something like: `if 'barytime' in data`.  You might also try `time = data.get('barytime', [])` which let's you return a default (in this case the empty list `[]`) if the item doesn't exist.

Comment: So would something like this work?
if data.names[0] == 'barytime'

  time = data['barytime']
else:
  time = data['time']
if data.names[7] == 'ap_raw_flux'
  brightness = data['ap_raw_flux']
else:
  brightness = data['sap_flux']


The reason I used 0 and 7 is because that's how the .fits file's data table is constructed (time/barytime, timeerr, stuff, stuff, blah, blah, blah,sap_flux/ap_raw_flux, etc)

Comment: It's a syntax error. I also learned that the location of "sap_flux" and "ap_raw_flux" are different in the data table. That could definitely be a potential problem. I'm sorry I'm asking you for so much help, I'm very new to python(less than two weeks) and there's so much out there that I don't know where to start.

Comment: I have another question: Your glob script works really well but for some reason, it doesn't process the data in order. Do you know of a way that I can tweak it so that it will?

Comment: @DaxFeliz what order do you want? You can always just sort the images with `files.sort()`.